# Abort Meteor startup immediately

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to abort Meteor startup in precisely the manner Meteor aborts startup when there's a JavaScript syntax error? I'm just concerned with development mode at the moment.

I can throw a new `Meteor.Error` from a startup block, but the app crashes several times before giving up and waiting for a file change.

When there's a JavaScript compile error, Meteor stops trying *immediately*, with a message similar to this:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While building the application:
   client/home/home.js:17:3: Unexpected string

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I'd like to cause *that* kind of error.

Comment: [npm](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm) seems to do something similar with `process.exit(0)`, however when I tried that after meteor started it just kept restarting. Maybe it only works when inside of a package.

Comment: It's the app-runner that's controlling this.  Have a look at [the source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/096df9d62dc9c3d560d31b546365f6bdab5a87dc/tools/run-app.js) - there seems to be a `watchForChanges` parameter that might do what you're looking for.